# .NET API to add document to .nsf HCL Lotus Notes database?

Tags: c#, .net, api, lotus-domino, hcl

I am hoping that someone with more domain knowledge in the community can help me out with HCL Notes and .NET related question.

I have a web app where there is a notes form allowing users to upload a file. I need to write an API that can add the file to an nsf database within Notes.

**What I have done**
I wrote the API, I am able to establish a connection to Notes and the nsf database. Here are some of my questions:

1. Will the Notes client need to be installed on the server this api will be deployed too?
2. Has anyone approached a similar problem ?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using the Notes COM or OLE classes (i.e., Lotus.NotesSession or Notes.NotesSession) or the Notes C or C++ APIs, then yes, you will need to have a Notes or Domino install on the server. You will need to address potential license questions related to this install with a representative of HCL or a reseller. If you are using the Domino Access Services REST API, then you do not have to have a Notes or Domino install on the server.
2. Yes, of course. Lots of people have dealt with similar cases in the last 30 years.
3. Huh?